# <p> Shows only last value assigned

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code, in which I try to achieve needed string("Hey!") by randomizing characters (brute-forcing the string), and to display all steps in a `<p>`(next step overwrites previous one). The problem is, however, that in the `#first`, there is only displayed the final step of permutations ("Hey!").

Why doesn't it displays all steps one after one, only the last one? I will appreciate any help on that problem.

**Note**: in the console, all steps are logged. I also tried outputting string in `<p>` with `timeout`; nothing changed.

**Example of what has to be:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk5cs.gif

Here's my Javascript code and HTML:

```js
var fline = ["H", "e", "y", "!"];
    temp_fline = [" ", " ", " ", " "],
    index = 0,
    possible = "!abc!defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!";

while (index < 4)
{
    if (fline[index] != temp_fline[index])
        temp_fline[index] = possible[Math.round(Math.random() * 57)];

    if (fline[index] == temp_fline[index])
        ++index;

    var tempString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        tempString += temp_fline[i];

    console.log(tempString);
    document.getElementById("fline").innerHTML = '> ' + tempString;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="first">
        <br>
        <p id="fline"></p>
        <br><br><br>
        <p id="sline"></p>
        <br><br><br>
        <p id="tline"></p>
        <br><br><br>
        <p id="fhline"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want like that?

```js
 var fline = ["L", "i", "k", "e", " ", "t", "h", "i", "s", "?"], count = 0, index = 0, flist = [],
    possible = "!abc!?defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ! ";

 let found = document.getElementById("found");
 let checking = document.getElementById("checking");
 
 let timer = setInterval(function ()
 {
  if (index >= fline.length)
  {
   console.log(flist);
   clearInterval(timer);
   checking.innerText = "";
   flist = [];
  }
  else
  {
   if (fline[index] == possible[count])
   {
    found.innerText += possible[count];
    flist.push(possible[count]);
    index++; count = 0;
   }
   else
   {
    checking.innerText = possible[count];
    count++;
   }
  }
 }, 24);
```

```html
<div><b id="found"></b><i id="checking"></i></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Probably, the issue was because of setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the innerHTML in every iteration of loop rather than adding to it

Try changing

```
document.getElementById("fline").innerHTML = '> ' + tempString;
```

To

```
document.getElementById("fline").innerHTML += '> ' + tempString;
                                        // ^^ concatenate instead of reassign
```

Comment: I need exactly to overwrite, if I'm not mistaken: I need to have an effect that the previous step is changed to the next, and so on; like the string is constantly changing.

Comment: Can you show sample of expected results in the question. Not really clear what you are looking for

Comment: Link to the GIF:
https://www.google.es/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwil84SQu4bcAhXDxRQKHVKWAu0QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2FProgrammerHumor%2Fcomments%2F8fsk0j%2Fhello_world_brute_force_python%2F&psig=AOvVaw1vqgoryM7DzQrv0krRAKGI&ust=1530828613026854

Comment: Add to question...not interested in following links all over the place. Questions should be self contained

Comment: Is it possible to add GIF to post? It converted into PNG when I tried to upload

Comment: It says that GIF format is not supported; added, however, link to the image to the question.

Comment: You need to use a timer to do that and make it visible to user

Comment: I tried to do it with setTimeout(here I change innerHTML property), as I mentioned in the question. Didn't work, though; the result remained the same.